# Swapping order of basemaps and overlays in Leaflet layers control?

Tags: leaflet, basemap

Is it possible to swap the order of the basemaps and overlays section in `L.Control.Layers`?

I would rather the basemaps were below the overlays, since that reflects the zIndex of them in the map.

Answer (score 2):

No. The order of that is hard-coded.

You can either use *two* instances of `L.Control.Layers`, or one of the many [plugins for "better" layer switchers](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls)